# Haxe: How to use a .NET C++/CLI dll in haxe code?

Tags: haxe

I've been trying to use Haxe to generate C# code that calls methods from a dll written in C++/CLR. This dll is called "AudioClientSDK.dll"

Here is an example of the Haxe code I'm trying:

```
package hello;

class HelloWorld {

    static public function main():Void {
        var s = untyped __cs__("AudioClientCLR.AudioClientAPI.release()");
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm using "Haxe magic" syntax (I previously tried Haxe extern classes that resulted pretty much in the same problems) to directly call the release method within the AudioClientSDK.dll. The method signature inside the dll is:

```
public : void AudioClientCLR::AudioClientAPI::release()
```

However, when I try to compile this code, Haxe throws this error:

```
haxe -cp src -cs out/CS -main hello.HelloWorld
haxelib run hxcs hxcs_build.txt --haxe-version 3103
c:\git\HelloHaxe\src\hello\HelloWorld.hx(6,16): error CS0103: The name
        'AudioClientCLR' does not exist in the current context
Compilation error
Native compilation failed
Error: Build failed
```

If I try to pass the AudioClientSDK.dll reference as -net-lib or -net-std I get these errors:

```
haxe -cp src -cs out/CS -net-lib lib/CPP/x86/AudioClientSDK.dll -main hello.HelloWorld
File "ilMetaReader.ml", line 281, characters 36-42: Assertion failed
error 0x2

haxe -cp src -cs out/CS -net-std lib/CPP/x86/AudioClientSDK.dll -main hello.HelloWorld
Error: No .NET std lib directory with the pattern 'net-20' was found in the -net-std search path. Try updating the hxcs lib to the latest version, or specifying another -net-std path.
```

Do any of you know how to correctly use the dll?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. These are some properties of the AudioClientSDK.dll:

- Targeted framework: .NETFramework,Version=v4.0
- Platform: Win32
- Platform Toolset: VisualStudio 2010 (v100)
- Use of MFC: Use MFC in a Shared DLL
- Common Language Runtime: Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)

Also, please note that this dll can be used without problems from C# in Visual Studio.

Comment: Have you checked against [this ticket](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/3847)? Looks as if this should be part of the [Haxe 3.2.0 RC](http://haxe.org/download/version/3.2.0-rc.2/). Tried that?

Comment: Thank you very much JensG, I just installed Haxe 3.2.0.RC but still got the same problems:

`$ haxe -cp src -cs out/CS -net-lib lib/CPP/x86/AudioClientSDK.dll -main hello.HelloWorld
File "ilMetaReader.ml", line 577, characters 34-40: Assertion failed
error 0x3`

`$ haxe -cp src -cs out/CS -net-std lib/CPP/x86/AudioClientSDK.dll -main hello.HelloWorld
Error: No .NET std lib directory with the pattern 'net-20' was found in the -net-std search path. Try updating the hxcs lib to the latest version, or specifying another -net-std path.`

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug. Please report it ASAP to the haxe issue list, with a downloadable link to the offending dll, and it might get included inyo the 3.2 final release

Comment: Thank you very much Waneck, I just opened the issue. http://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/4154

Answer (score 0):

very old question i know but there is a better way to do this (and it should work fine with any relatively new version of haxe 4)
do the --net-lib thing to link your DLL, then it should show up in the import context something like this (namespaces automatically become lowercase):

```
import audioclientclr.AudioClientAPI;

function main() {
    AudioClientAPI.release();
}
```